# How to make presentations in using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

I wanted to know that how can we make a presentations using HTML5. I am talking about the presentations that look like the Powerpoint presentations but are entirely made using HTML5,CSS3 and JavaScript. To point out to some example so that one could understand better just have a look on these pages whose link is mentioned below.

1. http://slides.html5rocks.com/#landing-slide
2. http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/#%281%29

and many other available online. Please provide me with a suggestion of frameworks used or some tutorials that can make my life easier with such presentations.

Comment: Step #1 Find an existing site for such (done) #2 *Learn from said site* (do now! :) #3 Profit! (pending).

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be after this kind of framework:
http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/html5-slideshow/

I do also believe this has been asked/answered on here before, but hope it helps!

Comment: Great article. I would get along and respond you back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at Eric Meyer's [S5](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can hand code HTML5/CSS3 which will take you a while;  You can use Google docs for very simple looking presentations.   If you want to go up a couple notches in design You can use this tool;  they're in Beta but it's pretty flexible and you can even animate your HTML5 objects;   [www.ewcPresenter.com](http://www.ewcPresenter.com)